# Automating write conflict messages

Tags: ms-access, multi-user, conflict

Is there any method to avoid the annoying write conflict messages by automating and hiding the process so that it doesn't appear as if the program is defective?   There doesn't seem to be any point to these messages anyway as there is only one real choice which is to drop the changes.

Comment: First, we need more context to offer advice. Second, you're completely mistaken about the choices available. In Access itself you can write your own code to handle the write conflict, though it's better to avoid conditions that produce it in the first place.

Comment: I question the value of the [multiuser] tag here. It adds nothing at all, since Access is by default multi-user enabled. Likewise, it's possible to generate a write conflict with a single user.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to avoid that message is to requery your screen after running a process or changing data on the backend database (or sql server)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle these errors in a combination of two places. The first, and most important is on the Form_Error event. Your code will look something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)    
    If DataErr = 7787 Then
        MsgBox "Oops, this record was edited by someone else or " & _
               "in another screen while you were making edits." & _
                "Your edits cannot be saved."
        Response = acDataErrContinue
    End If
End Sub
```

You will also need to handle error 3021 anywhere you run a Save command in VBA, like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 3021 Then
        'Do Nothing
        Resume Next
    Else
        'Handle other errors here
        Resume Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, I readily agree with one of the comments that it's more important that you try to resolve whatever is causing these errors rather than coding around them. In my case I am using the above solution to handle write conflicts that occur when a user opens two instances of the same form to the same record and makes edits in both instances. It would be better if I would prevent the user from opening the same record twice or prevent edits by only allowing the user to make edits in one of the open form instances but neither of these are exactly easy to implement, especially when you are using your own forms collection so I guess you could say I'm waiting for a "rainy day".